# Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: thinc/linear/linear.pyx

Tags: python, upgrade

While upgrading my system unsing `yay -Syu` the upgrade stops with following error.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1225, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: thinc/linear/linear.pyx
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
error: target not found: perl-test-most
```

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: Which package is actually being updated when you get this error? I assume it's not `perl-test-most`.

Comment: @Wieland Thank you for having a look. I can't say specific what I did, I *believe* the concerning package I needed to uninstall was python-pdfminer or python-thinc